# Can Meteor connect to MongoDB over SSL?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Can Meteor connect to MongoDB over SSL? If yes, what should `MONGO_URL` be set to so the connection is encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you simply need to include `ssl=true` in your `MONGO_URL` connection string, e.g.

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://user:password@ip:port/mydb?ssl=true`

See:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4812#issuecomment-129074941
- https://forums.meteor.com/t/what-mongo-url-to-connect-to-mongodb-server-with-ssl/13223

## Update:

Since writing this answer, I have actually tried and failed to use the `ssl=true` param in the `MONGO_URL` connection string.

This prompted me to explore the `Mongo.setConnectionOptions` method, and to publish [this simple package](https://atmospherejs.com/danwild/set-connection-options) that allows you pass in more advanced [connection settings](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In fact, on Meteor's free hosting all the Mongo connection urls are SSL connection urls. It works just fine because for low-level operations with MongoDB Meteor uses the same node-mongodb-native npm module which supports SSL.

Comment: Yes it does use the node-native-driver underneath. But SSL urls you refer to are for the application and not the database connection. The only configuration I know of for Meteor is the `MONGO_URL` environment setting. This is just a connection string, and the underlying driver cannot use SSL options in the connection string. At least in the supported version. The 1.4.x versions of the driver require a separate `Sever` object parameter. This is what the question is asking.

Comment: I might have rushed with this answer. Thinking about it again, Meteor's hosting is providing connections over ssl only when talking to the outside world (outside its local network), so only for mongo-shells

Comment: I can't imagine it being too hard if someone really wants to use ssl: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js#L121

Comment: Maybe so. Possibly some hacking with `MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver` where you could manually specify the connection options. But there is really nothing in this content that shows how it can be done. Which is what an answer should be.

Comment: your database needs to have ssl enabled and then it will automatically be an ssl connection

Comment: @sharkbyte are you sure? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#uri.ssl is `false` by default

Comment: I like how someone down-voted the guy who actually works for MDG.

Comment: This happened long time ago, I could have been wrong. I am a human too.

Comment: @imslavko https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4812 agrees with you! I haven't tested it, but apparently one can just add `?ssl=true` and (as long as the MongoDB server is configured properly) the connection between Meteor and MongoDB will be encrypted. Will you update your answer and I'll accept it?